# Application handler for cookies in .NET core 2.0

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have been reading through the sample for [Cookie](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/cookie/samples/2.x/CookieSample) based auth implementation by the ASP .NET core team. When I implemented a similar startup.cs file and tried to login I get a runtime exception

`InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Cookies`

How am I supposed to configure an application handler to validate my cookies?

Here's my code for reference.

**Configure method from Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        CookieBuilder builder = new RequestPathBaseCookieBuilder()
        {
            HttpOnly = false,
        };
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<CookieBuilder>(builder);
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>();
        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie = builder;
            options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateCookiePrincipal,

            };
        });
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

**Login method in account/login**

```
 [HttpGet("login")]
    public IActionResult Login() => Redirect(RedirectUrl()); //redirects to IdP url
```

**Validate IdP response method**

```
[HttpPost("/samlACS")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SamlACSAsync([FromForm] string samlResponse)
    {

        /*
         * if(saml response is successful)
         * {
         *      set cookie
         *      redirect to home url
         * }
         * 
         *  Redirect(OKTA sign in URL)
         * **/
        string nameID = ValidateSAMLResponse(samlResponse);
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, nameID)
        };
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
        };
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                authProperties
            );
        return LocalRedirect("/home");
    }
```